# FluentNHibernate filter with parameterized IN clause

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, filter

In Fluent NHibernate, is it possible to add a parameter to a filter of type `List<int>` so that the filter condition generates a `WHERE SomeColumn IN (@x, @y, @z)` ?

My use case is to fetch an invoice and a subset of its lines, given the ID of the invoice and a list of invoice line numbers. I want to eager fetch the lines in the same roundtrip as the invoice. I assume it is done something like this, but I cannot find the correct type declaration for the parameter type:

**Domain objects:**

```
public class Invoice {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public List<InvoiceLine> Lines {get;set;}
}

public class InvoiceLine {
  public int Id {get;set}
  public int LineNumber {get;set;}
}
```

**Mappings:**

```
public class InvoiceMap : ClassMap<Invoice> {
  public InvoiceMap() {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    HasMany(x => x.Lines).ApplyFilter<OnlyLinesWithNumbersFilter>();
  }
}

public class InvoiceLineMap : ClassMap<InvoiceLine> {
  public InvoiceLineMap() {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.LineNumber);
  }
}
```

**Filter definition:**

```
public class OnlyLinesWithNumbersFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public OnlyLinesWithNumbersFilter()
    {
        WithName("OnlyLinesWithNumbers");
        WithCondition("LineNumber IN (:LineNumbers)");
        AddParameter("LineNumbers",?? What to put here ??);
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
var filterName = "OnlyLinesWithNumbers";
session.EnableFilter(filterName).SetParameterList("LineNumbers", new[] {1,2,3});

var query = session.QueryOver<Invoice>()
       .Where(i => i.Id == 42)
       .Fetch(i => i.Lines).Eager
       .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

var result = query.SingleOrDefault();
session.DisableFilter(filterName);
```

Comment: Just a guess, try putting `AddParameter("LineNumbers", NHibernateUtil.GuessType(typeof(int[])));`

Comment: Thanks @Phill, but that fails with an "Incorrect type for parameter" (just as it does if I put any other type there)

Comment: Hmm, I think you might have to implement your own UserType which converts it to a comma separated string or something.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can figure that out - thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take-2

```
InvoiceLine invoiceLineAlias = null;
var list = session.QueryOver<Invoice>()
                  .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                  .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Lines, () => invoiceLineAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                  .WhereRestrictionOn(() => invoiceLineAlias.LineNumber)
                  .IsIn(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 })
                  .List();
```

produced sql:

```
SELECT
        this_.Id as Id2_1_,
        invoicelin1_.Invoice_id as Invoice3_3_,
        invoicelin1_.Id as Id3_,
        invoicelin1_.Id as Id3_0_,
        invoicelin1_.LineNumber as LineNumber3_0_
    FROM
        "Invoice" this_
    left outer join
        "InvoiceLine" invoicelin1_
            on this_.Id=invoicelin1_.Invoice_id
    WHERE
        this_.Id = @p0
        and invoicelin1_.LineNumber in (
            @p1, @p2, @p3
        );
    @p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
    @p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
    @p2 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
    @p3 = 3 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, the JoinType.LeftOuterJoin actually allows the eager fetch to work correctly. Does not seem logical to me why, though. And the produced SQL joins back and forth between invoice and lines and back to invoice ... but the result is correct.

Comment: +1 - I don't really understand why it works because giving it a test with and without the join type, produces the same query. But without it causes it to not keep the results. The question I asked on NHUsers suggested the same solution.

Comment: took me a while to figure out what the hell was going on, but it worked! Thanks!!!

Comment: The question is about how to solve a problem in a correct way and that problem is how to generate `WHERE SomeColumn IN` (first line of the question).

Answer (score 2):

To use NHibernate Filters with arrays, put NHibernateUtil.Int32 in AddParameter method, so do like this:

```
public class OnlyLinesWithNumbersFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public OnlyLinesWithNumbersFilter()
    {
        WithName("OnlyLinesWithNumbers");
        WithCondition("LineNumber IN (:LineNumbers)");
        AddParameter("LineNumbers", NHibernateUtil.Int32);
    }
}
```

And when you enabled filter, set an array in SetParameterList

```
int[] lines = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
session.EnableFilter("OnlyLinesWithNumbers").SetParameterList("LineNumbers", lines);
```

In my tests I use NHibernate 4.0.0.400

Answer (score 1):

you can write

```
var list = session.QueryOver<Invoice>()  
                  .WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.SomeColumn)  
                  .IsIn(someList)  
                  .List();
```

Comment: That is not, as far as I know, possible when "SomeColumn" is a collection (here the invoice lines)

Comment: @VahidH - That answer is completely unrelated to the question. He's asking about Table Filters, not a normal Query with an In-Clause.

Comment: @Jonas - If you want to write the filter at Query level, it is possible. I'll write up an answer for that if you like.

Comment: @Phill - that would be great, probably a nicer solution than the custom type.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct syntax, I just wrote this off the top of my head. :)

```
InvoiceLine invoiceLine = null;

var result = session.QueryOver<Invoice>()
                    .Where(x => x.Id == 42)
                    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.InvoiceLines, () => invoiceLine)
                        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.ItemNumber)
                        .IsIn(new[] {1, 2, 3})
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: This does not work as desired. It generates SQL similar to the following: SELECT * 
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN InvoiceLine il
ON i.Id=il.InvoiceId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice i2
ON i.Id=i2.Id
WHERE i.Id = 42 and il.LineNumber in (1,2,3)    . But does not correctly eager-fetch the lines, which means that ALL invoice lines are lazy loaded when the collection property is accessed.

Comment: Hmm I just got home, wrote a quick example and your right. I would consider that a bug.

Comment: I just posted a question on NHUsers with an example. http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/707be98a32891c64