# nhibernate fetching lazy loaded collection after I already assigned to the property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I'm using QueryOver and eagerly loading a filtered collection, similar to the following:

```
Part partAlias=null;
Session.QueryOver<Car>().JoinQueryOver(x=>x.Parts,()=>partAlias)
.WhereRestrictionOn(()=>partAlias.Id).IsIn(partIds)
.List<Car>();
```

The problem is that when I reference the resulting collection (.Parts) it gets fetched from the database and overwrites what I had before.  I'm using Fluent Nhibernate for config.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up getting everything to work.  There were a few different issues.  One was including other relationships that created a Cartesian product that caused collections to multiply. Another problem, which is more specific to my question here I solved by adding the join type as `JoinType.LeftOuterJoin`.  I found the advice on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6695743/265877).  The default is to use an inner join and that just doesn't work.  The join **MUST** be a left outer join.